# what is the right way to create a component instance in vue 3 in google chrome extension v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, vuejs3, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to create a component instance and append to the web page body with vue 3 in google chrome extension v3. This is my vue 3 component define:

```
<template>
    <div>I am a pop</div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        
    },
})
</script>

<style scoped>


</style>
```

the next step I tried to create an instance and tried to append the vue 3 component to the original web page body in google chrome extension content script. this is the code looks like:

```
let instance = new TranslatorPop()
instance.$mount();
document.querySelector('body')?.appendChild(instance.$el)
```

when run this app, shows error like this:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _public_widget_translator_TranslatorPop_vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is not a constructor
    at HTMLDocument.firstMouseUp (content.js:17199:24)
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to avoid this problem? I tried to do it like this:

```
const app = createApp(TranslatorPop);
app.use(store);
const vm = app.mount("#app");
document.querySelector('body')?.appendChild(vm.$el)
```

the app tell me error:

```
content.js:17410 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$el')
    at HTMLDocument.firstMouseUp (content.js:17410:56)
```

Comment: As far as I know you need a Vue root instance with `Vue.createApp`: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html

Answer (score 0):

try to mount like this:

```
let vm = app.mount("#uniq-anchor-point");
document.body.appendChild(vm.$el);
```

the uniq anchor point was the original web page uniq element, you can try to add a uniq element for any page then append your app element after this uniq element.